# Fix version - release management

Tags: jira, atlassian-sourcetree

We use our fixed version in the Jira to be something like this
XAR23.1 (projectname,year,number of release) in plain words for the year 2023 this is the release 1.

Recently the change management took over and said it’s crap and we need something like “XAR MAY Release 1”, I have a problem with putting a month in the naming because of following reasons:

1. Our fixed version is tied up with GitHub feature branch, if we in later point of time we decided not to have release we do not have to change anything. But if we put Month in the naming convention I need to rename the feature branch and all the developers who Downloaded the branch will need to check out the new branch again.
2. Easier to type.

What is the standard practise and which one is more suited, if we go my way is there any where we can capture which month 23.4 is installed.